# running a simple locust scritp and getting No connection adapters error

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I am running a very simple Locust script that is using the standard requests module and Python 3.7.7

The error is:
'in get_adapter
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '=https://.....'

Not sure where the '=' sign is coming from in the request url?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found the answer I had mistyped the cmd line for launching locust and had an extra = in there